# Navigation Bar .active doesn't appear to override the items in the links

Tags: html, css

I have a small situation in regards to my navigation bar I am creating for a site. I am curious if I did something incorrect, or does the text color in my .active in the external css compared to what I have set up in the ul. in the ul I have the text as #fff, and I would like the text in the .active to be #003721, however the text in the .active remains as #fff.

Below is what I have so far for the code:

```css
/*NavBar*/
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:200px;
background-color: #003271;
border: 1px solid #fff;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
}

li{
text-align: center;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

li:last-child{
border-bottom:none;
}

li a{
display: block;
color: #fff;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
background-color: #555;
border: 1px solid #fec500;
color: white;
}

.active{
background-color: #fff;
color: 003271;
border:1px solid #fec500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Anchor Studios</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/home.css">
  <script src="js/home.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--Vertical Navbar-->
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.html">Log In</a></li>
   <li><a href="url">Register</a></li>
   <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Community">Community</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Series">Series</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Shop">Shop</a></li>

  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to put `#` before the color `003721`.

```css
/*NavBar*/
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:200px;
background-color: #003271;
border: 1px solid #fff;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
}

li{
text-align: center;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

li:last-child{
border-bottom:none;
}

li a{
display: block;
color: #fff;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
background-color: #555;
border: 1px solid #fec500;
color: white;
}

.active{
background-color: #fff;
color: #003271;
border:1px solid #fec500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Anchor Studios</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/home.css">
  <script src="js/home.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--Vertical Navbar-->
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.html">Log In</a></li>
   <li><a href="url">Register</a></li>
   <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Community">Community</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Series">Series</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Shop">Shop</a></li>

  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your color code `003271` should have a `#` before it like this:

```
.active{
    color: #003271;
}
```